# Haskell: cartesian product of a list with itself n times

Tags: haskell

What's a simple way of computing the cartesian product of a list with itself `n` times?

That is, how can I define the function `cartesianExp :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]`.

For instance, the cartesian product of `[1,2]` with itself 3 times (`n = 3`) should be:

```
[
 [1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 2],
 [1, 2, 1],
 [1, 2, 2],
 [2, 1, 1],
 [2, 1, 2],
 [2, 2, 1],
 [2, 2, 2]
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can work with [**`replicateM :: Applicative f => Int -> f a -> f [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM) to do this. Indeed:

```
ghci> import Control.Monad(replicateM)
ghci> replicateM 0 "abc"
[""]
ghci> replicateM 1 "abc"
["a","b","c"]
ghci> replicateM 2 "abc"
["aa","ab","ac","ba","bb","bc","ca","cb","cc"]
ghci> replicateM 3 "abc"
["aaa","aab","aac","aba","abb","abc","aca","acb","acc","baa","bab","bac","bba","bbb","bbc","bca","bcb","bcc","caa","cab","cac","cba","cbb","cbc","cca","ccb","ccc"]
ghci> replicateM 3 [1,2]
[[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[2,1,1],[2,1,2],[2,2,1],[2,2,2]]
```

Comment: Would the following be a correct interpretation of this behaviour? The list monad models non-deterministic behaviour, and `replicateM` makes an action that collects the list of results from repeating the given action `n` times. Thus `replicateM n list` can be seen as performing the nondeterministic experiment `list` (the list specifies the possible outcomes) `n` times, so the result is a nondeterministic `n`-tuple of outcomes drawn from `list`. The set of all such `n`-tuples is precisely the cartesian product of `list` with itself `n` times.

Comment: @Anakhand: yes, `replicateM n` will make *n* "choices". But these are not tuples, but lists.

Answer (score 4):

```hs
import Data.List


cartesianExp :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
cartesianExp 0 _ = [[]]
cartesianExp n xs = [x:tup | x <- xs, tup <- cartesianExp (n - 1) xs]
```

By convention, the cartesian product of a set *S* with itself 0 times, *S<sup>0</sup>*, is the set consisting of a single empty tuple.

Then, the cartesian product of a set *S* with itself *n* times, *S<sup>n</sup>*, can be defined inductively by expanding each of the tuples in *S<sup>n-1</sup>* by each of the elements in *S*.

(Here I'm using the mathematical meaning of the terms set and tuple, in the Haskell implementation they both correspond to lists in this case.)